# Laravel response send android APK file

Tags: php, laravel, http

I'm using this code to send an android APK file to client, the client download this file very well but the client can not parse this file, probably because of the mime type.

```
return response()->file($path ,['Content-Type'=>'application/vnd.android.package-archive']) ;
```

The client gets a file with this name "android" without any extension. How can I send android file to client with extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
return response()->download($pathToFile, $name, $headers);
```

but download() function will tell the client to download the file from the web server so the path of your file must point to “public” folder of your website. But if your files are protected and you want your Laravel application to send the file, then use this snippet

```
return response()->file($path ,[
    'Content-Type'=>'application/vnd.android.package-archive',
    'Content-Disposition'=> 'attachment; filename="android.apk"',
]) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **download()** in which you could pass the name of the file as a second argument:

`return response()->download($pathToFile, $name, $headers);`

Comment: What should be the $headers array?

Comment: Have you tried using yours `['Content-Type'=>'application/vnd.android.package-archive']`? You can also just add the first 2 parameters of the method.